# VBA Excel to Word - Save as pdf failing on second run of loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, pdf, ms-word

I have the below code which runs through as expected for the word creation when I add in the section for save to pdf it runs and saves the first time through. The second loop it builds the word file and saves the file but fails to complete the pdf creation a second time round. I get the following error after the second word file has finished in the loop.

Run time error '462'
The remote server machine does not exist or is not available

Quite new to VBA so be gentle with my code!!

Thanks in advance,

David

```vb
Sub CreateBasicWordReport()
    
    Dim WdApp As Word.Application
    Dim SaveName As String
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim LstObj1 As ListObject
    Dim MaxValue As Integer
    Dim FilterValue As Integer
    Dim Organisation As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
   
    Set LstObj1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   
    MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(LstObj1.ListColumns(1).Range)
    
    FilterValue = MaxValue
    
    Do Until FilterValue = 0
    
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "Static"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    With WdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        
        .Documents.Add "C:\Users\david\Documents\Custom Office Templates\IBD Registry Quarterly Report Template2.dotx"
      
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterValue
    Range("F11").Select
              
    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    
    .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="TableLocation"
    .Selection.Paste
    
    For Each Row In Range("Table1[#All]").Rows
    If Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = Row
        Set Rng = Union(Row, Rng)
    End If
    Next Row
    Set WS = Sheets("Static")
    Rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1")

    Sheets("Static").Select
    Sheets("Static").Activate
    Organisation = Range("D2").Value
    
    Sheets("Static").Select
    Range("D2").Copy
    .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Organisation"
    .Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Sheets("Static").Select
    Range("F2").Copy
    
    .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="MalePatients"

    .Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Chart2.ChartArea.Copy
    
    .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="ChartLocation"
    .Selection.Paste
    
    If .Version <= 11 Then
        FileExt = ".doc"
    Else
        FileExt = ".docx"
    End If
    
    SaveName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\IBD Registry Quarterly Report for " & _
        Organisation & " " & _
        Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & FileExt
        
    If .Version <= 12 Then
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveName
    Else
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 SaveName
    End If
    
    SaveNamePDF = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\IBD Registry Quarterly Report for " & _
    Organisation & " " & _
    Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".pdf"

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:=SaveNamePDF, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF _

    
    .ActiveDocument.Close
    .Quit
    
    End With
    
    Set WdApp = Nothing
    
    FilterValue = FilterValue - 1
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Static").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First step - you're doing lots of things in the loop that presumably should be outside it, such as `Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`, `.Quit`, and `Set WdApp = Nothing`.

Comment: Yes I think it looks like I was opening and closing the word application every time rather than just closing a document. Starting to make sense now most of my coding is in SQL so this is new way of thinking for me. Appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BigBen pointed out you have some commands inside your loop that should be outside it. I have rewritten your code to show you how you can some additional improvements that will help optimize your code.

VBA code runs more quickly if you avoid selecting things. This applies equally to Excel and Word. Both applications have `Range` objects that can be used in place of `Selection`.

You also have an undeclared variable in your code, `Row`, so you should add that to your variable declarations, (preferably using a different name though as `Row` is an object in Excel and confusion can occur when variables have the same name). You can avoid these issues by adding Option Explicit at the top of the code module. This will prevent your code from compiling when you have undeclared variables. To add this automatically to new modules open the VBE and go to Tools | Options. In the Options dialog ensure that Require Variable Declaration is checked.

On the whole though it's not a bad start for someone new to VBA.

```
Sub CreateBasicWordReport()
   Dim WdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.document
   Dim SaveName As String
   Dim FileExt As String
   Dim LstObj1 As ListObject
   Dim MaxValue As Integer
   Dim FilterValue As Integer
   Dim Organisation As String
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim WS As Worksheet
   
   Set LstObj1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   
   MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(LstObj1.ListColumns(1).Range)
    
   FilterValue = MaxValue
    
   Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Do Until FilterValue = 0
    
      Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "Static"
      Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
      'moved outside of loop
      ' Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   
      With WdApp
         .Visible = True
         .Activate
         'create new document and assign to object variable
         Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add("C:\Users\david\Documents\Custom Office Templates\IBD Registry Quarterly Report Template2.dotx")
      'now mostly finished with WdApp as from here wdDoc is used
      End With
      ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterValue
      Range("F11").Select
              
      Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="TableLocation"
      '         .Selection.Paste
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("TableLocation").Range.Paste
    
      For Each Row In Range("Table1[#All]").Rows
         If Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = Row
            Set Rng = Union(Row, Rng)
         End If
      Next Row
      Set WS = Sheets("Static")
      Rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1")

      '      Sheets("Static").Select
      '      Sheets("Static").Activate
      Organisation = WS.Range("D2").Value
    
      '      Sheets("Static").Select
      '      Range("D2").Copy
      WS.Range("D2").Copy
      
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Organisation"
      '         .Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("Organisation").Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
      '      Sheets("Static").Select
      '      Range("F2").Copy
      WS.Range("F2").Copy
      
    
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="MalePatients"
      '         .Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("MalePatients").Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
         
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
      Chart2.ChartArea.Copy
    
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="ChartLocation"
      '         .Selection.Paste
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("ChartLocation").Range.Paste
    
      If .Version <= 11 Then
         FileExt = ".doc"
      Else
         FileExt = ".docx"
      End If
    
      SaveName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\IBD Registry Quarterly Report for " & _
         Organisation & " " & _
         Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & FileExt
        
      If .Version <= 12 Then
         ' .ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveName
         wdDoc.SaveAs SaveName
      Else
         ' .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 SaveName
         wdDoc.SaveAs2 SaveName
      End If
    
      SaveNamePDF = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\IBD Registry Quarterly Report for " & _
         Organisation & " " & _
         Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".pdf"

      wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
         OutputFileName:=SaveNamePDF, _
         ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF _

    
         wdDoc.Close
         'moved outside of loop
    
         'are you sure that these need to be inside the loop?
         FilterValue = FilterValue - 1
         Sheets("Static").Delete
    
   Loop

   WdApp.Quit
    
   Set WdApp = Nothing
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That has done the trick thanks so much. I had to make a few changes it didn't seem to like .version also I notice it saves a .doc rather than .docx using the version setting. Should that be switched?

Comment: Sorry, that should be WdApp.Version

Comment: Just went I think that has solved it I seem to get odd results occasionally the table is sending the text to the organization position and the graph is being duplicated. Somewhat like the loop is not keeping the same number of steps each run.

Comment: @dcfretwell - As BigBen commented earlier, you need to post this as another question